# Strut2 having multiple packages cause problems

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, struts2

This is my package structure in Struts.xml file

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">


    <!-- Default action name <default-action-ref name="Index" /> -->

    <action name="Index" method="index"
        class="com.convergent.struts2.actions.UserAction">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/WEB-INF/html/index.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>

<include file="struts-admin.xml"></include>
```

My Index.jsp is access through this url

```
http://localhost:8888/Index
```

In Index page there is hyper link that redirect that user to Setting Page. Setting action is in the 'Admin' namespace so it is access as:

```
<a href="<s:url action='Admin/Setting'/>">Setting</a>
```

In setting page there is a hyper link to redirect the user to index.jsp page. action is called like this:

```
<a href="<s:url action='Index'/>">go back</a>
```

As you can seen 'Index' action is in the default package having namespace '/'. So to handle this action namespace is changed and user is redirected to the index.jsp page. My problem is that although user is redirected to index.jsp page but the web url looks like

```
http://localhost:8888/Admin/Index
```

I want this url to

```
http://localhost:8888/Index
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: "As you can seen 'Index' action is in the default name space." - no it is in the default package and the namespace "/". Advice: 1) Don't create namespaces without leading a leading '/', it generally isn't want you want. 2) Use the namespace attribute of the struts2 url tag.

Comment: Also Struts2 has an anchor tag, where you can specify properties of the action mapping that would render accordingly the theme you use.

Comment: Forgot to add I don't know why use framework and don't use templates? Haven't discouraged yet?

Comment: @RomanC you are suggesting to use freemarker templates or any other one?

Comment: @Quaternion I follow your second advice and its work. can you give the answer to my question in proper way so that every one knows the right answer.

Comment: @RomanC I tries to use Struts2 anchor tag and set the namespace attribute but It didn't work. can you give me a proper example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As you can see 'Index' action is in the default name space." - no it is in the default package and the namespace "/".

Advice: 1) Don't create namespaces without leading a leading '/', it generally isn't want you want. For basic use of namespaces see http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/namespace-configuration.html although that page does not cover the creation of namespaces without a leading slash, and the interesting behaviour you've experienced.

2) Use the namespace attribute of the struts2 url tag. When using Struts the tag reference is your friend: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/tag-reference.html

As Roman mentioned, using the anchor tag will be a touch more straight forward.

Using just the url tag you would have:

```
<a href="<s:url namespace='/' action='Back'/>">go back</a>
```

When this is a bit clearer:

```
<s:a namespace="/" action="Back">go back</s:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem what i do rather than redirecting the user to index.jsp I first redirect the user to another action like this

```
<a href="<s:url action='Back'/>">go back</a>
```

To handle this action mapping in struts-admin.xml is:

```
        <action name="Back">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
            <param name="actionName">Index</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

This way I solve the problem.

Comment: You'll make the user visit an intermediary page before going where they want to go? This isn't pretty.

Comment: I don't find other way so I do in this way. can you give me another solution?